# Database restore fails due to consistent RESTORE command

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, restore, server-farm

I have a backup of a sharepoint 2010 farm that I am attempting to restore using Central Admin.

One of the reasons for failure is a content database restore that fails, the error is:

```
Object WSS_PO_Content failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
SqlException: The restart-checkpoint file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\RestoreCheckpointDB11.CKP' is from a previous interrupted RESTORE operation and is inconsistent with the current RESTORE command. The restart command must use the same syntax as the interrupted command, with the addition of the RESTART clause. Alternatively, reissue the current statement without the RESTART clause. 
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally
```

I reconstructed the restore command from the restore log and it still produces the same error. The content database is overly large due to it not being set up or managed correctly (it's 230GB).

The location of the farm backup is on a network share.

Other errors I encountered:

```
Object WSS_Content_8888 failed in event OnPostRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
SPUpgradeException: This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm.

Object WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_StagingDB_6f2cd37f-cefa-4c9e-a220-1ca5631fb9e2 failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
SqlException: Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use. 
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

***UPDATE***

I updated the patch status to match that of the source sharepoint installation.

I appreciate any help.

thanks.

Comment: when you took the sharepoint backup? i mean version of backup and sharepoint farm( where restoring) is on same level? do you have the SQL backup of content db?\

Comment: Hi, i just checked and it seems that the Sharepoint patch status from which the backup was taken is slightly higher for several components. The SQL backup is in the farm backup folders.

Comment: You cant go from higher to lower version. You need to upgrade the target farm as the source farm. both farm should be on same patch level.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurred when you have the mismatch between the backup farm and restore farm.You should make sure

- Both farm( Source & target) should be on same patch level.

You cant go from Higher Version of SharePoint to Low version. as you mentioned your source farm is higher version then target.

http://vikramvaje.blogspot.com/2012/08/this-content-database-has-schema_10.html

Comment: Now that the patch status is the same on both source and destination server - do i need to delete the databases already created?

Comment: Also, I tried to restore from the checkpoint but it fails with the same error. I'm thinking I need to remove the databases and restart the full farm restore - thought?

Comment: quick question, what you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to restore a farm backup from server A to server B.

Comment: Full backup from Farm A and then restore it to Farm B? or just taking the DB backup from A and restore it to Farm B?

Comment: I need a full farm backup restored.

Comment: delete all the database which partially restored, cleanup up the stuff, then try to run the restore